# Inline C assembler macros for an AVR RTOS

Tags: c, assembly, embedded

I am trying to write a preemptive scheduler for AVR and therefore I need some assembler code ... but I have no experience with assembler. However, I wrote all the assembler code I think I need in some C macros. At compilation I get some errors related to assembler (constant value required and garbage at and of line), which makes me think that something is not correct in my macros ...

The following macro, load_SP(some_unsigned_char, some_unsigned_char), sets the stack pointer to a known memory location ... I am keeping the location in the global struct aux_SP;

Something similar is with load_PC(...) which is loading on the stack, a program counter: "func_pointer" which is actually, as the name suggest, a pointer to a function. I assume here that the program counter as well as the function pointer are represented on 2 bytes (because the flash is small enough)

For this I am using processor register R16. In order to leave this register untouched, I am saving its value first with the  macro "save_R16(tempR)" and the restoring its value with the macro "load_R16(tempR)" where "tempR" as can be seen is a global C variable.

This is simply written in a header file. This along with another two macros (not written here because of their size) "pushRegs()" and "popRegs()" which are basically pushing and then popping all processors registers is ALL my assembler code ...

What should I do to correct my macros?

```
// used to store the current StackPointer when creating a new task until it is restored at the
// end of createNewTask function.
struct auxSP
{
    unsigned char auxSPH;
    unsigned char auxSPL;
};

struct auxSP cSP = {0,0};

// used to restore processor register when using load_SP or load_PC macros to perform
// a Stack Pointer or Program Counter load.
unsigned char tempReg = 0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////// assembler macros begin ////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// save processor register R16
#define save_R16(tempR)                                 \
    asm volatile(                                       \
            "STS tempR, R16                     \n\t"   \
                );

// load processor register R16
#define load_R16(tempR)                                 \
        asm volatile(                                   \
                    "LDS R16, tempR             \n\t"   \
                    );

// load the Stack Pointer.              Warning: Alters the processor registers
#define load_SP(new_SP_H, new_SP_L)                     \
    asm volatile(                                       \
                "LDI R16, new_SP_H              \n\t"   \
                "OUT SPH, R16                   \n\t"   \
                "LDI R16, new_SP_L              \n\t"   \
                "OUT SPL, R16                   \n\t"   \
                );

// load the Program Counter on stack.   Warning: Alters the processor registers
#define load_PC(func_pointer)                           \
    asm volatile(                                       \
                "LDS r16, LOW(func_pointer)     \n\t"   \
                "PUSH r16                       \n\t"   \
                "LDS r16, HIGH(func_pointer)    \n\t"   \
                "PUSH r16                       \n\t"   \
                );
```

Comment: Read in the gcc documentation how to use C parameters and variobles in the inline assembly.

Comment: For a successful thread switch, you must restore **all** registers to the state they were in when you interrupted the thread.  This means your timer interrupt routine has to not only save all the registers it sees, but inspect the stack to recover values pushed there by the interrupt hardware logic (the right value for the PC is there). The ISR prologue generated by the compiler also pushes some values onto the stack. The order in which the registers are restored is also of crucial importance.

Comment: @MichaelRoy As mentioned, there are the macros pushRegs() which push all the registers on the stack and popRegs() which pop all the registers from the stack. These macros are used in other functions ...

Comment: As an aside, the AVR has very little RAM. Reserving space for several stacks will waste quite a bit of RAM.

Comment: @MichaelRoy I am reserving 64 bytes for every stack ... and this is something more for academic use ... I am interested in some concepts

Comment: np. the asm statements need to have clobber and usage statements, The compiler expects to see a couple of semi-columns ;; between the last assembly statement and the closing parenthesis.

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: Please provide a small code to see what you sir, mean ...

Comment: It is even useless for the academic tests, as any not prehistorical family of uC provides at list two levels of execution and some hardware mechanisms for this task. Use even simpliest ARM STM32f1 microcontroller instead. There is no practical and theoretical use of impkementing task switching on the obsolete architecture

Comment: Not from me.  I never vote on questions.

Comment: @PeterJ I am a familiar with AVR and I want to start here :)

Comment: @PeterJ.  It is possible to do it on the AVR.  But going down this route will probably not allow for a useful application.  Using a reentrant timer interrupt would be much more viable solution.

Comment: @CMarius Since you are doing this for research, you should  have a look at RTOS, and how this is done for various processors, including the AVR. http://www.freertos.org/a00098.html

Comment: @MichaelRoy I've already done that

Answer (score 1):

Your main source of reference for this should be http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html

Avoid using "unsigned char" - use "uint8_t", as it is shorter and more explicit.  Avoid macros - use static inline functions instead whenever possible.  Don't invent your own struct for auxSP, especially not using a different endian ordering than the target normally uses - just use uint16_t.  Don't write things in assembly when you can write them in C.  And don't split up asm statements that need to be combined together (such as preserving R16 in one statement, then using it in a second statement).

Where does that leave us?

It's a long time since I have done much AVR programming, but this might get you started:

```
static inline uint16_t read_SP(void) {
  uint16_t sp;
  asm volatile(
    "in  %A[sp], __SP_L__ \n\t"
    "in  %B[sp], __SP_H__ \n\t"
  : [sp] "=r" (sp) :: );
  return sp;
}

static inline void write_SP(uint16_t sp) {
  asm volatile(
    "out  __SP_L__, %A[sp] \n\t"
    "out  __SP_H__, %B[sp] \n\t"
  :: [sp] "r" (sp) : );
}

typedef void (*FVoid)(void);
static inline void load_PC(FVoid f) __attribute__((noreturn));
static inline void load_PC(FVoid f) {
  asm volatile(
    "ijmp"
  :: "z" (f) );
  __builtin_unreachable();
}
```

You will probably also want to make sure you disable interrupts before using any of these.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of C code I did on an AVR platform. It is not macros but functions because it was more adapted for me.

```
void call_xxx(uint32_t address, uint16_t data)
{
    asm volatile("push r15"); //has to be saved
    asm volatile("ldi r18, 0x01");  //r15 will be copied to SPMCSR
    asm volatile("mov r15, r18"); //copy r18 to r15 (cannot be done directly)
    asm volatile("movw r0, r20"); //r1:r0 <= r21:r20 //should conatain "data" parameter
    asm volatile("movw r30, r22"); //31:r30<=r23:r22 // should contain "address" parameter ...
    asm volatile("sts 0x5b, r24"); //RAMPZ
    asm volatile("rcall .+0"); //push PC on top of stack and never pop it
    asm volatile("jmp 0x3ecb7");  //secret function
    asm volatile("eor r1, r1"); //null r1
    asm volatile("pop r15");  //restore value

    return;
}
```

Also try without your `\n\t` this may be the "garbage at and of line"

The problem of constant value required may come from here :

```
#define save_R16(tempR)                                 \
    asm volatile(                                       \
            "STS tempR, R16                     \n\t"   \
                );
```

For this I am less sure but STS (and other) requires an address that may need to be fixed at compile time. So depending on how you use the macro it may not compile. If tempR is not fixed, you may use functions instead of macro.

Comment: If you're going to do that, just write your whole function in asm.  That's going to break if/when it inlines into anything.  If you need a scratch reg, you should just ask the compiler for one with a dummy output constraint.  (See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for info on writing inline asm that lets the compiler optimize as much as possible without wasting instructions.)